# Using laravel assets from assets dir

Tags: php, laravel

I have a js file:  resources/assets/js/main.js

In my blade I tried to access it as:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/main.js') }}"></script>
// or
<script src="{{ asset('assets/js/main.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{!! asset('js/main.js') !!}"></script>
<script src="{!! asset('assets/js/main.js') !!}"></script>
```

It resolves the url to mydomain.dev/js/main.js giving me a 404. 
How can I get this to work?

Comment: The web root of `mydomain.dev` is in `public`, not `resources`. Typically, your JavaScript build process (webpack, gulp, etc.) would process your JS files and create stuff in `public`.

Comment: Ok, so only webpack tasks etc should use asset() helper? I will never use that myself in blade files?

Comment: You'll use `asset` in Blade, but `asset` is for linking to stuff in the `public` directory. Trying to link to `resources` stuff won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Please see this link, you do not need to store your external files to assets directory, use public directory only,

```
asset();
url();
```

both get your project url.
please see this i hope you will understand what i am saying 
[laravel assets directory](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/include-css-and-js?page=1)

Comment: Thanks for vote brother if it solved your issue then do not forget to mark as right...

Answer (score -1):

step 1) you need to register your js file in blade like this

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/main.js') }}"></script>
```

step 2) make sure your js file lies in public directory as it will take js file from public/js

step 3) just clear cache with this command :-

```
php artisan config:cache
```